# Add timer to flutter_sound when recording voice

Tags: flutter

How can I show the timer to the user when recording sound with [flutter_sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound)?

I have a text widget that I want to display a timer in that text widget when the voice is recording.

```
Text(
   recordingTime,
   textAlign: TextAlign.center,
   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
),
```

```
Future<void> startRecording() async  {

   await _voiceRecorder!.startRecorder(
     toFile: _voicePath,
     codec: _codec,
   );

   //start timer

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've tried it. try it like this.

First, Add package intl: ^0.18.0 to pubspec.yaml file.

And add **_recordingTime** variable to widget you have like below.

```
class RecorderTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RecorderTestState createState() => _RecorderTestState();
}

class _RecorderTestState extends State<RecorderTest> {
  String _recordingTime = '00:00:00';
```

Make **_initSetting()** method

```
 Future<void> _initSetting() async {
_voiceRecorder?.setSubscriptionDuration(Duration(milliseconds: 10));
    await initializeDateFormatting();
  }
```

And call it in your **openTheRecorder()** method.

```
Future<void> openTheRecorder() async {
    if (!kIsWeb) {
      var status = await Permission.microphone.request();
      if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        throw RecordingPermissionException('Microphone permission not granted');
      }
    }
    await _voiceRecorder!.openRecorder();
    await _initializeExample();
...
}
```

It will be called in initState()

```
@override
  void initState() {
    openTheRecorder();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Now, add the code below to your **startRecording()**

```
_voiceRecorder!.onProgress!.listen((e) {
      var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(e.duration.inMilliseconds,
          isUtc: true);
      var txt = DateFormat('mm:ss:SS', 'en_US').format(date);
  setState(() {
    _recordingTime = txt.substring(0, 8);
    _dbLevel = e.decibels;
    isRecording = true;
  });
});
```

As a result of adding code.

```
Future<void> startRecording() async  {

   await _voiceRecorder!.startRecorder(
     toFile: _voicePath,
     codec: _codec,
   );

    _voiceRecorder!.onProgress!.listen((e) {
          var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(e.duration.inMilliseconds,
              isUtc: true);
          var txt = DateFormat('mm:ss:SS', 'en_US').format(date);
      setState(() {
        _recordingTime = txt.substring(0, 8);
        _dbLevel = e.decibels;
        isRecording = true;
      });
    });

  }
```

Then, you can see  a timer in your screen.

My result

[image]